# Twilio Call Forwarding Call Quality

Tags: asterisk, twilio

I have an asterisk pbx setup in Dubai. this PBX is suppose to take calls then send it through SIP to twilio which will forward the calls to a number in the UK. which I manged to do successfully using SIP and twimlets, so the calls are now forwarded but the voice quality is so poor.

I have tested forwarding to a land line and Skype Line, both of them did not work well as the voice quality was very poor and sometimes it is only silence without even a ring.

I am trying to identify the source of this issue, tips and trails will be great to see how to push this forward.

Comment: which codec is used? Is it a G.726/32 kbps or G.711 Call? If the codec is GSM, i wouldn't expect good quality.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be in many things.

Good point is to get the INVITE packet (use sip set debug on) and see codec that was negotiated.

Try to register SIP softphone directly to that * PBX box and route calls to it. If the problem still persist then you know it is not between your PBX and Twilio and landline.